# IE6 Select Box - How to align disabled styling

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

To give some context, I have a form with a number of fields that have to be disabled dynamically, using jQuery, dependent on query string values obtained. Because I want these values posted back to the server, I am making use of the 'readonly' attribute and then overriding styling. For my drop down boxes, I have noticed that using the readonly attribute will not prevent the user from being able to select further, so I've instead disabled these elements and provided matching (hidden) elements that I can use for posting their values to the server.

However, when I use the disabled=disabled attribute on my select and then tweak the background-style (as per what I've done on other input boxes), I do not get the expected greyed out background in IE6. All other versions of IE and major versions of FF and Chrome are absolutely fine; it's just IE6 where the issue occurs. Following is my code. Has anyone else come across this issue and/or know a work-around?

Many thanks
Ian

```
// Disable the drop downs completely
$("#Division").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#Country").attr("disabled", "disabled");

// Style boxes
$("input[type=text]").css("background", "lightgray");
$("#R").css("background", "lightgray");
// Re-styling for the drop downs - works across all browsers EXCEPT IE6
$("select").css("background-color", "lightgray");
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you even wasting time with IE6 for? you're aware that no one uses it anymore, even Internet Explorer 7 isnt worth your time of day [see here](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) for global statistics.

Comment: I'm well aware of that Matt, unfortunately this is internal demands of a client :)

Comment: Purely out of interest... Why are you entertaining this for your client. With the greatest of respect; it is your job to convince your client not to use a 13 year old web browser with extensive security holes.